# Finding the classes of all the table tags using BeautifulSoup and the number of p tags

Tags: python

**soup.findAll("p")** #for finding the p-tag but how will I know how many p-tags are there

and,
how can I find classes of all the table tags

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
len(soup.findAll("p"))
```

To get a list of all the p tags in the html.
Then you can count with len() the amount of the p tags in the list.
For getting all class of the table tags you can use

```
[i["class"] for i in soup.findAll("table")]
```

that will return a list of lists for each tag all the classes of the tags.